# Change link text based on browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that I want to change the content "Post Your Need" to "✎" when the browser drops below 40em width. I've tried googling for a solid half hour to no avail. Any help here? I'm looking for jquery/javascript.

```
<a class="postbutton" href='post.php'>Post Your Need</a>
```

EDIT:

The insistence of all y'all got me thinking about CSS instead of jquery. In the end I created a second anchor tag with the pencil icon and used media queries to place it above the viewport. So when it crosses over the query line, the bigger tag moves up with "margin-top: -2em" and the smaller one moves down. It's awesomely simple, allows me to apply separate CSS rules to the two elements, and when resizing the browser having them move up and down looks pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1. Change the CSS

You could achieve this through css alone ([sample](http://jsfiddle.net/L706tmLp/1/)):

```
@media (max-width: 40em) {
    // when smaller than 40em...
    .postbutton {
        // resize postbutton... hiding overflow
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 13px;    
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .postbutton:before{
        // and insert this text at the beginning
        content: '✎';
    }
}
```

## Option 2. Change the HTML and CSS

Alternatively, and semantically better, you could change the markup and css. Simply replace the contents of `<a class="postbutton">` with the following markup ([sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lkkfsn6/)):

```
<span class="collapsed">✎</span><span class="expanded">Post Your Need</span>
```

Then you can target those elements specifically with css:

```
.postbutton .collapsed
{
    // hide the collapsed text by default
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 40em) {
    // when smaller than 40em...
    .postbutton .collapsed {
        display: inherit; // show the collapsed text
    }
    .postbutton .expanded {
        display: none; // hide the expanded text
    }
}
```

<sub>See the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo element and [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

as codename said there is a simple css option: media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

but if you are set on using jquery you can get the window's width by doing:

```
$(window).width(); // returns the width of the window
// do stuff when the window is resized
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(window).width(); // the new width
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the way I try to get the Browser width in em works ...
But why not do it in px?

```
var minWidth = 40; // Define minWidth
$(window).resize(function() {
  // Get Browser width in em
  var w = $(window).width() / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
  // Compare Browser width to defined minWidth
  if(w < minWidth) {
    // If Browser window is smaller than the defined minWidth, set small Link Text
    $(".linkClass").html("[new HTML Content]");
  } else {
    // If Browser window is bigger or equal to minWidth, set big Link Text
    $(".linkClass").html("Post your need");
  }
}
```

Note: Untested, might need some tweaking

Edit: Whoops ... 40em not 30 :-)